# Using map and lambda to emulate a dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of tuples that are coordinates: `xy = [(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ...]` and an specific point `xy_sp = [x_sp, y_sp]`. I want to calculate the distance from each point to the so called "specific point" and to create a dictionary in the form: `{coordinates_of_1st_point: distance_1, coordinates_of_2nd_point: distance_2, ...}` and then perhaps I just can order my dictionary by values.

I want to do this with a functional pythonic approach. So I did:

```
import numpy as np
distances = list(map(lambda k: np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(k) - np.asarray(xy)), xy))
```

And then I just created a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_distances = {k : v for k, v in zip(xy, distances)}
```

It is this last point that I want to do with a maps and lambdas in a functional approach but I don't know how to do it. If it can be all done in a line of code it would be interesting, although I suppose it will be not readable at all and therefore not very recommendable.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: `dict` comprehensions **are the functional approach**. Comprehension-constructs were borrowed from Haskell, a purely functional language.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I was thinking that the "Haskellian" approach were the map, filter and reduce functions combined with lambda functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `lambda` for that, just call the built-in `dict` on the result from `zip`:

```
dict_distances = dict(zip(xy, distances))
```

Builds a mapping from the 2-tuple returned by `zip`.